# While displaying data from sqlite database , for every onitemclick same data loads

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have written a program to insert json data into sqlite database in the form of a listview which is working perfectly , and with internet on , on every item click the details are also displaying correctly in the next activity.
But once when the data is loaded and i turn off the internet to load the data through sqlite database , the listview is displaying correctly but on every item click the details on the next activity are always the item which was last viewed.

```
cursor = listHelper.getAllData();
        String[] columns = new String[] { DbListHelper.ARTWORK_IMAGE, 
                DbListHelper.WRAPPER_TYPE,
                DbListHelper.ARTIST_NAME, DbListHelper.COLLECTION_NAME, 
                DbListHelper.TRACK_NAME,
                DbListHelper.COLLECTION_PRICE, DbListHelper.TRACK_ID };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.artworkImage, R.id.wrapperType, 
                R.id.artistName, R.id.collectionName,
                R.id.trackName, R.id.collectionPrice, R.id.trackId };

        dataAdapter = new CustomImageTextCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
        R.layout.custom_row, cursor, columns, to);
        lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
                position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final int item_id = 
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.UID));
                String item_content1 = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(0)));
                String item_content2 = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(1)));
                String item_content3 = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(2)));
                String item_content4 = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(3)));
                String item_content5 =  
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(4)));
                String item_content6 = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(5)));
                String item_content7 =                 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(6)));
                String item_content8 = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (cursor.getColumnName(7)));
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
                intent.putExtra("trackId", item_content8);
                SingleTunesDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

CustomImageTextCursorAdapter.java :

```
public class CustomImageTextCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context context;
private SqliteListHelper listHelper;
String extStorageDirectory;
File folder;
File file;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
int layout;
ConnectionDetector connectionDetector;
FileCache fileCache;

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView wrapperType, artistName, collectionName, trackName, collectionPrice,trackId;
    ImageView artworkImage;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        wrapperType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.wrapperType);
        artistName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
        collectionName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.collectionName);
        trackName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trackName);
        collectionPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.collectionPrice);
        artworkImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.artworkImage);
        trackId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trackId);
        listHelper = new SqliteListHelper(context);

        listHelper.open(context);
    }
}

public CustomImageTextCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, 
    String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(context);
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
}

public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, 
    false);
    itemView.setTag(new ViewHolder(itemView));
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    // you might want to cache these too
    int index = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.UID);
    int cid = c.getInt(index);
    int index0 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.ARTWORK_IMAGE);
    String cid0 = c.getString(index0);
    int index1 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.WRAPPER_TYPE);
    String cid1 = c.getString(index1);
    int index2 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.ARTIST_NAME);
    String cid2 = c.getString(index2);
    int index3 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.COLLECTION_NAME);
    String cid3 = c.getString(index3);
    int index4 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.TRACK_NAME);
    String cid4 = c.getString(index4);
    int index5 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.COLLECTION_PRICE);
    String cid5 = c.getString(index5);
    int index6 = c.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.TRACK_ID);
    String cid6 = c.getString(index6);

    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    vh.wrapperType.setText(cid1);
    vh.artistName.setText(cid2);
    vh.collectionName.setText(cid3);
    vh.trackName.setText(cid4);
    vh.collectionPrice.setText(cid5);
    vh.trackId.setText(cid6);
    vh.trackId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(cid0, vh.artworkImage);
    } else {
        File file = fileCache.getFile(cid0);
        Log.i("TAG", "file_ path :" + file.getPath());
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        vh.artworkImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

}
```

SingleItemDetails.java : In this class i am displaying json data from a url with parameter trackId passed from previous activity.

```
public class SingleItemDetails extends Activity {

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "";

// JSON Node names
static final String TAG_RESULT = "results";
static final String TAG_ARTWORK_IMAGE = "artworkUrl100";
static final String TAG_WRAPPER_TYPE = "wrapperType";
static final String TAG_ARTIST_NAME = "artistName";
static final String TAG_COLLECTION_NAME = "collectionName";
static final String TAG_TRACK_NAME = "trackName";
static final String TAG_COLLECTION_PRICE = "collectionPrice";
static final String TAG_TRACK_ID = "trackId";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray tracks = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> singleTrackDetails;

String passedData1;
TextView wrapperTypeText, artistNameText, collectionNameText, trackNameText, 
collectionPriceText;
ImageView trackImage;
String artworkImage, wrapperType, artistName, collectionName, trackName, 
collectionPrice, trackId;

private SqliteListHelper listHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_track);
    singleTrackDetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    wrapperTypeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrapperType1);
    artistNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artistName1);
    collectionNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collectionName1);
    trackNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trackName1);
    collectionPriceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collectionPrice);

    passedData1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("trackId");

    listHelper = new SqliteListHelper(getBaseContext());

    listHelper.open(getBaseContext());

    url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" + passedData1;

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetSingleTrackDetails().execute();
}

class GetSingleTrackDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private JSONObject jsonObj;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                tracks = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = tracks.getJSONObject(i);

                    artworkImage = c.getString("artworkUrl100");
                    wrapperType = c.getString("wrapperType");
                    artistName = c.getString("artistName");
                    collectionName = c.getString("collectionName");
                    trackName = c.getString("trackName");
                    collectionPrice = c.getString("collectionPrice");
                    trackId = c.getString("trackId");

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> tunesMap = new HashMap<String, 
                    String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    // contact.put(TAG_ID, firstname);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_ARTWORK_IMAGE, artworkImage);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_WRAPPER_TYPE, wrapperType);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_ARTIST_NAME, artistName);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_COLLECTION_NAME, collectionName);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_TRACK_NAME, trackName);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_COLLECTION_PRICE, collectionPrice);
                    tunesMap.put(TAG_TRACK_ID, trackId);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    singleTrackDetails.add(tunesMap);

                    long id = listHelper.insertData2(artworkImage, 
                    wrapperType, artistName, collectionName,
                            trackName, collectionPrice, trackId);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Cursor cursor = listHelper.getAllData2();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
            String item_content1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(0)));
            String item_content2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(1)));
            String item_content3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(2)));
            String item_content4 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(3)));
            String item_content5 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(4)));
            String item_content6 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(5)));
            String item_content7 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(6)));
            String item_content8 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (cursor.getColumnName(7)));

            wrapperTypeText.setText(item_content3);
            artistNameText.setText(item_content4);
            collectionNameText.setText(item_content5);
            trackNameText.setText(item_content6);
            collectionPriceText.setText(item_content7);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong ?
Thank You

Comment: If you are using custom adapter, could you share `Adapter` for your `ListView` or see what you are having in `public Object getItem(int position)` of your `Adapter`

Comment: yes sir please check the code above

Comment: @Mithun sir , when my internet is on , the details of the selected item is showing correctly , but when i internet is off , the details on my new activity are being shown of the item which i viewed it last before i turned off my net , can u tell me what should i do now ?

Comment: @Mithun sir , i found out the solution myself, thanx for your reply